# さくらレンタルサーバーにおけるPythonでのMeCabのimport方法

Tags: python, flask, mecab, pip, さくらインターネット

とりあえずshellをbashに変更しました。
Flaskのファイルを実行したいのですが、うまく行きません。

追記：
現状Pythonファイルを実行するとこのような感じになっています。

```
import MeCab
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MeCab'
```

type mecab : `mecab is /usr/local/bin/mecab`
which mecab : `/usr/local/bin/mecab`

```
% pip3 install mecab
Collecting mecab
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement mecab
No distributions at all found for mecab

% pip3 install mecab-python
Collecting mecab-python
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement mecab-python
No distributions at all found for mecab-python


% pip install --upgrade pip
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in ./.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/envs/3.6.4-flask/lib/python3.6/site-packages (10.0.1)
% pip install mecab-python3
Collecting mecab-python3
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/25/e9/bbf5fc790a2bedd96fbaf47a84afa060bfb0b3e0217e5f64b32bd4bbad69/mecab-python3-0.7.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: mecab-python3
  Running setup.py install for mecab-python3 ... error
    Complete output from command /home/sky--ward/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/envs/3.6.4-flask/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/home/sky--ward/tmp/pip-install-vcj90d0h/mecab-python3/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /home/sky--ward/tmp/pip-record-g6zmjjvw/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/sky--ward/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/envs/3.6.4-flask/include/site/python3.6/mecab-python3:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.freebsd-9.1-RELEASE-p24-amd64-3.6
    copying MeCab.py -> build/lib.freebsd-9.1-RELEASE-p24-amd64-3.6
    running build_ext
    building '_MeCab' extension
    creating build/temp.freebsd-9.1-RELEASE-p24-amd64-3.6
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/home/sky--ward/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/envs/3.6.4-flask/include -I/home/sky--ward/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/include/python3.6m -c MeCab_wrap.cxx -o build/temp.freebsd-9.1-RELEASE-p24-amd64-3.6/MeCab_wrap.o
    cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wstrict-prototypes" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
    MeCab_wrap.cxx: In function 'PyObject* _wrap_Lattice_set_result(PyObject*, PyObject*)':
    MeCab_wrap.cxx:5583: error: 'class MeCab::Lattice' has no member named 'set_result'
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command "/home/sky--ward/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/envs/3.6.4-flask/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/home/sky--ward/tmp/pip-install-vcj90d0h/mecab-python3/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /home/sky--ward/tmp/pip-record-g6zmjjvw/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/sky--ward/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/envs/3.6.4-flask/include/site/python3.6/mecab-python3" failed with error code 1 in /home/sky--ward/tmp/pip-install-vcj90d0h/mecab-python3/
```

Comment: 念の為、`which mecab` または `type mecab` の結果を教えて頂けませんか？

Comment: mecabが`/usr/local/bin`にある場合は、`~/.bashrc`に`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin`に追加し、bashを起動しなおすか, `source ~/.bashrc`で設定を強制的に読み込めばPATHが通ると思います。

Comment: @yoshi さん、「PATHを通す」というのは今回の場合、Python で `MeCab` パッケージを使いたいということであり、ターミナルの上で `mecab` コマンドを使いたいのではないということでよろしいでしょうか？　多くの場合「PATHを通す」というと後者のことを指す気がしていて、若干齟齬があるように思っています。

Comment: @nekketsuuu さん、確かにそうですね、申し訳ありません。訂正します…

Comment: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MeCab'`は PATHの問題ではなく、pythonのmecabモジュールをインストールしていないことが問題なのかと思いました。 `pip install mecab-python`とかが必要では?

Comment: @tanalab2 Mecabはそもそも入っていると思います…
一度試してみます。ありがとうございます。

-追記-
試しました。
本文に追記しました。

Comment: python3の場合、`pip3 install mecab-python3` のようです。追記されたものはいずれも`Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement xxx`となっています。

Comment: % pip3 install mecab-python3
Collecting mecab-python3
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement mecab-python3
  No distributions at all found for mecab-python3

Comment: pipコマンドが古いのですかね。`pip install --upgrade pip`してから、`pip install mecab-python3`してみるとどうでしょうか?

Comment: @tanalab2  結果を追記しました。

Comment: `MeCab_wrap.cxx:5583: error: 'class MeCab::Lattice' has no member named 'set_result'`とありコンパイルできないようです。mecab-python3はmecabのpython用バインディングであるため、mecabを事前にインストールしておく必要があるのですが、事前にインストールされたmecabのバージョンが古いためビルド失敗しているのだと思います。そのため、mecab 0.996以降のバージョンがインストールされているか確認してください。(set_resultは2013-02-18 MeCab 0.996から導入された機能のようです。http://taku910.github.io/mecab/)

Comment: サーバー管…理？質問はサーバの管理運用方法の内容じゃないですよね？このタグ不要では？

Answer (score -1):

web上のいくつかの記事を見る限りでは`/usr/local/bin`以下にインストールされているようです。実際の環境でもbashに**切り替える前**に`which mecab`でPATHを確認されてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: こんな感じでした。
>type mecab : mecab is /usr/local/bin/mecab
>which mecab : /usr/local/bin/mecab